# Is there a JavaScript alternative to PIL?

Tags: javascript, python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to convert some old python code to JS and I'm having trouble finding an alternative to it. These are some examples of the python code I'm trying to convert.

```
image_array = np.ones([16, 16, 4],np.uint8)*255
im = Image.fromarray(image_array)
im.save(name)
----------------------------
image = Image.open(new_image_filename)
impt = np.array(image)
```

Sorry if this doesnt make sense - thanks for taking the time to look at it

Comment: Are you talking about Javascript in `node.js`?  There are certainly image processing packages for `node.js`, but I would argue that Python is a better platform, because of `numpy`.

Comment: `Image` is not defined, `name` is not defined, `new_image_filename` is not defined... and presumably `np` comes from `import numpy as np`.....  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please explain what your code needs to _do_ rather than showing code you have that doesn't really do anything meaningful: creating an image from a numerical array is trivially done in the browser using a canvas element, and can be done in even more ways with pretty much any image editing package in Node, which can readily be found with a web search. And the same is true for opening an image and getting its pixel data. [What did you already search for and how did that not work for you?](/help/how-to-ask)